# Отменить изменения в значениях собственного (owned) типа

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

В моей модели есть `DbSet` включающий в себя сущность`ParticipantPerson`, которая имеет имеет собственный тип `NameCompany`

```
[Table("ClientCompanies")]
public class ClientCompany : ICloneable, IClient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public NameCompany Name { get; set; } = new NameCompany();

    public object Clone()
    {
        ClientCompany result = new ClientCompany();
        result.Id = Id;
        result.Name = (NameCompany)Name.Clone();
        return result;
    }
}

[Owned]
public class NameCompany : ICloneable, IName
{
    public string NameShort1 { get; set; }
    public string NameLong1 { get; set; }
    public object Clone() { return MemberwiseClone(); }
}
```

Вопрос в том, чтобы изменить свойства сущности в `ClientCompany.Name` и потом откатить изменения к начальным значениям не меняя каждое свойство вручную и не вызывая новый экземпляр объекта из базы данных.

**Что я пробовал:**

1. Напрямую присваивать SelectedClient ссылку на ReserveCopy

   ```
   var SelectedClient = db.ClientCompanies.Find(1);
   SelectedClient.Name.NameShort1 = "ООО Ромашка";


   //Создаем резервный клон объекта
   var reservedCopy = (ClientCompany)SelectedClient.Clone();
   //Меняем значения
   SelectedClient.Name.NameShort1 = "СМУ";
   //Присваиваем SelectedCompany ссылку на reservedCopy
   SelectedClient.Name = reservedCopy.Name;
   ```

Отката не происходит, хотя `reserverdCopy` сохраняет изначальное значение "ООО Ромашка".

2. Использовать CurrentValues и SetValues сущности

   ```
   var SelectedClient = db.ClientCompanies.Find(1);
   SelectedClient.Name.NameShort1 = "ООО Ромашка";

   //Меняем значения
   SelectedClient.Name.NameShort1= "СМУ";

   //Присваиваем SelectedCompany ссылку на reservedCopy
   //Используем свойства OriginalValues и CurrentValues
   db.Entry(SelectedClient).CurrentValues.SetValues(db.Entry(SelectedClient).OriginalValues);
   db.Entry(SelectedClient).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
   ```

Результат: Отката изменений не происходит, поскольку `OriginalValues` и `CurrentValues` затрагивают только собственные столбцы сущности, а не ее собственные типы.

3. Попытаться изменить CurrentValues собственного типа

   ```
   var SelectedClient = db.ClientCompanies.Find(1);
   SelectedClient.Name.NameShort1 = "ООО Ромашка";

   //Меняем значения
   SelectedClient.Name.NameShort1= "СМУ";

   //Ошибка: У типа отсутствует метод "SetValues" если только он не является сущностью в контексте.
   db.Entry(SelectedClient).Reference("Name").CurrentValue.SetValues
   ```

Результат: `Ошибка: у собственного типа отсутствует метод SetValues`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для данной схемы EF Core считает `NameCompany` отдельной сущностью. И, соответственно, отслеживает изменения в ней отдельно.

Проилюстрироваать это можно следующим образом:

```
var selectedClient = db.ClientCompanies.Find(1);                
selectedClient.Name.NameShort1 = "ООО Ромашка";
Console.WriteLine(db.Entry(selectedClient).State);      // Unchanged
Console.WriteLine(db.Entry(selectedClient.Name).State); // Modified
```

Следовательно, когда вы хотите откатить изменения, то нужно их откат применять именно к свойству `Name`:

```
db.Entry(selectedClient.Name).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Теперь при вызове `db.SaveChanges();` не будет сделано обновление значений в БД.